# JQuery/JS multipage based on number of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, phoenix-framework

I apologize in advance if this is really simple question, I'm just not familiar with JS, thus not sure how to make it. Basically, I have div ID which holds loaded elements from database (using Elixir/Phoenix):

```
      <div id ='chicken'>
        <%= for chicken <- @chickens do %>
          <%= render MyApp.OrderItemView, "chicken.html", changeset: @order_item_changeset, action: order_order_item_path(@conn, :create, @order), chicken_id: chicken.id, chicken_price: chicken.price, chicken_name: chicken.name %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
```

So my page looks smth like this:

```
<div id = 'chicken'>
 <div class="menuitems"></div>
 <div class="menuitems"></div>
 <div class="menuitems"></div>
</div>
```

Where each class "menuitems" is a separate element loaded. Here is an example with 6 elements: 
[image: example]

My problem is that I'm trying to have multiple pages. So if there are more than 6 elements, it's not going to fit, thus I need a button to the next page. For example if there are under 10 elements, first 6 should be visible, while others should be on another page(should be button for next page).

Edit(as pointed in the comments): That's what I have so far: `var numItems = $("#chicken").children('div').length;`

Any suggestions, recommendations appreciated, as I'm really not sure how to make it. I assume i need to count elements, and if more that 6 create "next page".

Comment: Why you dont handle paging on server side? Are you sure you really want to hide rendered elements by jquery?

Comment: Hey @AliSheikhpour, I was planning to have animation when switching between pages, therefore didn't consider server-side handling. Is it a bad idea to do it that way?

Comment: When you have large number of data, it would be bad idea to force CPU and browser and then hide rendered elements! You can animate between results using ajax loading data and trigger the animation on ajax success. However if you have few amount of data, you can use your own method.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating @AliSheikhpour . The amount of data is quite low, actually no more than 25 elements, so I believe that's won't be too resource-hungry. As for the JS, is it Pagination, i have to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change,

```
var numItems = $(".chicken").children('div').length;
```

**to**

```
var numItems = $("#chicken").children('div').length;
```

because if you are using "chicken" as an ID then you need to use "#" and not "." I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I'm reading now about pagination, is that what I need for having multiple pages?

Comment: Don't count the number of div that comes under "chicken" Id, Instead when  you fetch the data from the database fetch only first 6 records, later if you have more than 6 elements in the database you just simply enable the next button, And on the 'next' button click event, fetch next 6 elements from the database, in html clear the previous html DOM and redraw those div with latest 6 elements. this is a kind of basic pagination you can do. clearing the previous DOM and redrawing can easily be done through jQuery.

Comment: You can even use slides js for sliding effect (Kind of animation). This is the plugin you can use, where you can fetch all the data once(As u mentioned there will not be more than 25 records) and give it to the plugin, plugin then handles everything i.e. <<PREV  NEXT>>.

Comment: Thanks @Vish, I'll try to follow your suggestion!